# Android configuration screen when installing

Tags: android

I need to display a configuration screen when a user installs my application. Is this possible to implement? That screen should not appear again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to display a configuration
>   screen when a user installs my
>   application.

That is not possible. Applications do not get control at install time. As nicholas.hauschild indicates, you can perform your configuration on first run of your application.

Answer (score 6):

I do not think this is possible at install time, unless perhaps, you are dealing with rooted Android devices.

What you could do is have an Activity that starts the first time you run the application, which would be your configuration Activity.

I imagine you could do this using some of Android's built in Preferences.  Have a boolean Preference which is whether or not the user has completed the initial configuration, and have it checked each time the user starts the application.  If they have not completed it, start the configuration Activity and when they complete it, switch the flag.  If they have completed it, start your application normally.